# How to read an input of Real Numbers and use them

Tags: c, floating-point, double

Hello I have very little experience with coding but the problem that I am working on for school requires me to have an input such as " 12.5 " and have that input be processed to give me a certain output.

I am trying to modify this code to do that but with no luck

The code is in C

For example the "**rate**" would be something like "**12.5**", but it only reads the "**12**" and then it continues the calculations with the **12**, and ignores the **.5**

I need it to read the whole **12.5**

Thanks for any help available.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int hours_2weeks;
    int rate;
    int Gross_Pay;
    int Social_security_tax;
    int Federal_tax;
    int State_tax;
    int Medical_dental;
    int Net_Pay;
    printf("\nPayroll Program for X Y Z Corp.\n");
    {
    printf("Enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%d", &hours_2weeks);

    printf("Enter hourly rate: ");
    scanf("%d", &rate);
    }
    printf("This employee worked %d hours with a salary of $%d per hour. Here is the salary statement for this employee:\n",hours_2weeks,rate);

    Gross_Pay=hours_2weeks*rate;
    printf("Gross Pay: %d\n", Gross_Pay);
    Social_security_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.06;
    printf("Social security tax: -%d\n", Social_security_tax);
    Federal_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.1;
    printf("Federal tax: -%d\n", Federal_tax);
    State_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.05;
    printf("State tax: -%d\n", State_tax);
    Medical_dental=hours_2weeks*rate*.05;
    printf("Medical/dental: -%d\n", Medical_dental);
    Net_Pay=hours_2weeks*rate-(hours_2weeks*rate*.06)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.1)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.05)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.05);
    printf("Net Pay: %d\n", Net_Pay);
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, rate cannot be *int*, since *int* is for integer values only. There are floating point types such as *float* or *double*. When inputting, you should use *%f* instead of *%d* to read floating point values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are defining all the input variables as Integer. even if you type a double, the system will covert/cast those values to integers...

You are doing this:

```
 int hours_2weeks;
 printf("Enter hours worked: ");
 scanf("%d", &hours_2weeks);
```

do instead:

```
double hours_2weeks;
printf("Enter hours worked: ");
scanf("%lf", &hours_2weeks);
```

Answer (score 2):

`rate` is an integer variable. Change it to `float`, as well as change the `scanf` call to

```
scanf("%f", &rate);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you need a decimal point you have to change your datatype to `float` or `double` and when you do that mind that you have to change the format specifier to `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared rate as : `int rate;` , what it does is, the rate variable now can store only Integral values (like 1,4,66,3333, although it has an upper bound) and not Floating Point numbers (like 3.55, 4.2112, 34.533, numbers with decimals).

To be able to store a float value ( numbers with decimals ), you need to delare rate as : `float rate;` .
Also to enable printing of float values to the console output, you need to replace the format specifier of printf and scanf to `%f` from `%d`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks now it does what I needed it to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{

float hours_2weeks;
float rate;
float Gross_Pay;
float Social_security_tax;
float Federal_tax;
float State_tax;
float Medical_dental;
float Net_Pay;
//printf("\nPayroll Program for X Y Z Corp.\n");
{
printf("Enter hours worked: ");
scanf("%f", &hours_2weeks);

printf("Enter hourly rate: ");
scanf("%f", &rate);
}
printf("This employee worked %d hours with a salary of $%d per hour. Here is the salary statement for this employee:\n",hours_2weeks,rate);

Gross_Pay=hours_2weeks*rate;
printf("Gross Pay: %.2f\n", Gross_Pay);
Social_security_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.06;
printf("Social security tax: -%.2f\n", Social_security_tax);
Federal_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.1;
printf("Federal tax: -%.2f\n", Federal_tax);
State_tax=hours_2weeks*rate*.05;
printf("State tax: -%.2f\n", State_tax);
Medical_dental=hours_2weeks*rate*.05;
printf("Medical/dental: -%.2f\n", Medical_dental);
Net_Pay=hours_2weeks*rate-(hours_2weeks*rate*.06)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.1)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.05)-(hours_2weeks*rate*.05);
printf("Net Pay: %.2f\n", Net_Pay);
}
```